# Joomla How to get a dynamic list of files from a folder as options in a xml file

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla-extensions, dynamic-list, xmlformview

I'm working on a Joomla 3.6 extension and the xml file which contains the options for a form in the plugin for users to select should be filled dynamically according to all the file names in a particular folder of my extension. I know there is a way to dynamically retrieve values from a database table but that is not what I'm looking for.

The thing is, users can add custom skins for JW Player and upload them to the folder, so somehow I have to present all files (except index.html) in that option list, since I do not know how many extra skins there are.
So far, I worked with static list options, like:

```
<field name="skin" type="list" default="" label="selectskin">
    <option value="">Standard</option>
    <option value="beelden">Beelden</option>
    <option value="bekle">Bekle</option>
    etc...
```

But in that case, custom skins won't be listed.
Any suggestions?

Thank you beforehand :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different form fields. One of them is `Filelist form field type` You can check details here -
 https://docs.joomla.org/Filelist_form_field_type

If you want to exclude any file there is also an option for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Irlan. I will try it out.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks again, Irfan!

Comment: @RudolfB : Good to know :) You can also accept this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers